# How to pass oid parameter to postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, function, python-3.x, psycopg2

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Persons"
(
    id_persons serial NOT NULL,
    name_persons varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    telephone_persons varchar(14) NOT NULL,
    email_persons varchar(100),
    address_persons integer NOT NULL,
    photo_persons oid,
    login_persons varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    password_persons varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    type_persons public."PersonTypes" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Client',
    CONSTRAINT "Persons_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id_persons),
    CONSTRAINT "Persons-email_ukey" UNIQUE (email_persons),
    CONSTRAINT "Persons-login_ukey" UNIQUE (login_persons)
);
```

On my local pc I have a `photo.gif` file and I need send this file to the `photo_persons` column in `Person` table.

I want to do this through a stored procedure and using  the `cursor.callproc()` psycopg2 method.

I need a few examples of stored procedure and psycopg2 examples to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `oid` you need to pass is the `oid` of the large object itself, not of a function.

Assuming some connection object `conn`:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
```

Large objects can be created and populated in a few ways, e.g.:

```
# Open for writing in binary mode. No oid is passed, so a new object
# will be created.
new_lob = conn.lobject(mode="wb")

# Stash the newly allocated oid.
new_oid = new_lob.oid

# Put some data in the object.
new_lob.write(b"some data")

# And close it out.
new_lob.close()
```

Alternatively, to create and populate a large object from a file local to where the code is running, you could do something like:

```
# Open for writing in binary mode. No oid is passed, so a new object
# will be created. psycopg2 will take care of loading the contents
# of the file named "somefile.ext".
new_lob = conn.lobject(mode="wb", new_file="somefile.ext")

# Stash the newly allocated oid.
new_oid = new_lob.oid

# And close it out.
new_lob.close()
```

To load data from a previously created large object, pass in the `oid` to `lobject`, e.g.:

```
# Open the object identified by new_oid in binary reading mode.
loaded_lob = conn.lobject(oid=new_oid, mode="rb")

# Load all of its data.
loaded_lob.read() == b"some data"
```

If you use the second approach to creating the object, i.e. by passing in the filename, you can then pass the generated `oid` to your function that then stores that identifier in your table. And note that you likely want to do both of those steps - creating the large object and creating the table entry - in the same transaction.

Comment: But I have a postgresql store procedure for save data in a table called `Person`. This function expected receive many parameters, one of then is a oid type called `photo`.
What must I pass to the `photo` parameter when I to call the store procedure with `cursor.callproc()`?

It would be a `lobject` object? eg. `cur.callproc(par1, par2,...., any_lobject)` ?

Comment: If the `photo` parameter is supposed to be the `oid` of an existing `lobject` then you pass in the `oid` like in the example above, e.g. `new_lob.oid`.

Comment: In this case, the binary file must be beforehand stored in the database, it's correct?
But in my case, the image file is on the local PC and needs to be sent to the database through stored procedure.

Comment: Can you please update your question to describe your function, database schema, and intended workflow? The original question was focused specifically on passing oids around, which it has become clear is too narrow to address what you're actually having trouble with.

Comment: The binary file needs to be inserted separately with `new_lob.write(b"some data")`?
Is there any way to do everything with stored procedure and callproc? Ie pass the binary to the stored procedure and not only the oid?

Comment: Technically you could call `.write` to iteratively put new chunks of data, which is useful if you're streaming bytes. But if you already have the file saved somewhere you can just pass the filename to `.lobject` to have psycopg2 populate the object from there. That object allocation and population should happen outside of the stored procedure, which should just take the `lobject` oid. I've updated the answer with these details.

Comment: At what time the file comes into existence in the database?
At same moment that lobject is created?